# Flip Custom ListView's item with front and back views with animation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I want a good example that can flip a custom ListView's listitem with two different views (front and back) by applying 180 degree rotation animation.
in simple words, i have a custom listview that has a list item with some buttons, now i want it to be flipped when a user click a button on front view in listitem and show the back view which contains a TextView.

I tried googling all the solutions and also tried every possible solution which are on StackOverFlow. but none of them worked exactly.

Please help me if you have a good example / Tutorial for this

Comment: take a look at these two links:
[Card flip animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html#animate) &  [Propery animaion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property)

Comment: @Harry, I ListView Adapter has a raw file and both the views are instantiated via this file. So i don't want to use fragment instead.
But thanks for your efforts

Comment: You do not need to use fragment, what i suggested was to use the animations used in 'card flip' link on list view items.